# SharePoint required people picker field

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We have an environment set up where we use a people picker field in a list.
The people picker is a required field.

There are a lot of different required fields and if they aren't filled out the form wont save to the list.

However if I try doing the same with the people picker field the form saves EVEN WHEN the field is empty!!!!

Is this one more of the quirks of SharePoint or do I need to fix something?

EDIT: as it seems that I'm confusing everybody here goes from the beginning.

I have made a people picker field called Approving manager"

[image]

This field is now added to a form on a list and as you can see it the field is marked with a *

[image]

Now when I fill the form and skip filling out the "Approving manager" field SharePoint lest me ( this isn't allowed with any other field type!! )

So here is the end product

[image]

As shown in the picture the item is added to the list and as you can clearly see the Approving manager field is blank.

So I am asking if the people picker doesn't care if it is required or not or if there is something more/else I have to do to make the field behave?

Comment: Could you please tell how are you setting People Picker as required field?

Comment: with standard SharePoint functionality. there is NO code.

Comment: can not reproduce this, please tell exactly how you've set up the field

Comment: Can u explain in detail , what you want to exactly do ?

Comment: @DipenShah I did in the edit of my post